# how many matches are played

Tags: functions

so the question is the are a total of 16 teams. Each team will play each other once so each team will play 15 matches since they can't play themselves. How many matches in total are played?

Answer (score 1):

There are 16 teams that can be chosen as the first team in a game, and for each team, 15 teams they can play.  But this approach overcounts by a factor of 2, because you have counted team A (first player) playing team B (second player) as well as team B (first player) playing team A (second player).  Thus the answer is $16 \times 15/2 = 120$.

Comment: okay this is what i expected but the reason why im confused is say for example you split the teams into two groups. in both groups their are 8 teams, each team will play the other teams in the group but in a  2 game series. so this comes out to 8 x 14/2 = 56 total games in one group. then 56 x 2 = 112 since their are two groups and that is the total number of game played. but why is the number different then the format where every team played each other once.

Comment: Because when you have two groups, the teams do not play teams in the other group.  Each team now plays  $14$ games instead of $15$.  Why did you expect the same answer to two different problems?  In fact, $120 \cdot \frac {14}{15}=112$

Comment: the reason i thought that was because although the team are now split into two groups the teams in the group will now play the other teams in the group in 2 game series instead of just 1 match like in the first question. i was thinking that alone would make up the difference.

Comment: In your approach, teams in one group do not compete against all other teams in the same group.